# Failure to calculate expression: wrong sum being computed

Tags: java, expression

I have written a class that describes a polynomial object. I collect and send the array of coefficients to the class and the value that the user desires to have the polynomial calculated for BUT for some mysterious reason that only java knows the class keeps sending back a completely wrong calculation of the polynomial. I have worked at this for 3 hours and can't find a solution this this treacherous problem.What is wrong the class?I have included the tester class plus the actual class.
This is the output of the program by the way:
2 2 2 2 (these are the coefficients that I have entered} You are evaluating for a value of: 2.0
 The sum of the polynomial is:
32.0

2x^0+2x^1+2x^2+2x^3 (As you can see this is the wrong answer its supposed to be 30)

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


    public class copy1D{

        public static void main(String[]args)
        {

            String input;
            int degree;
            double number;


            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" what is the degree of the polynomial?");
            degree = Integer.parseInt(input);
            degree= degree+1;
            int [] array = new int [degree];

            //creating array of coefficients
            for ( int i =0; i<=array.length-1; i++)
            {
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter coefficients:");
                array[i] = Integer.parseInt(input);
            }

            //Printing out the coefficients to ensure they are correct
            for ( int i =0; i<=array.length-1; i++)
            {
                System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
            }



            Class1D c1d = new Class1D(degree, array);


            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter the number for which to evaluate the expression:");
                number = Integer.parseInt(input);
                System.out.println(" You are evaluating for a value of: " + number);
                System.out.println(" The sum of the polynomial is:");
            System.out.println(c1d.Evaluathepolynomial(number));

                for (int z=0; z <= array.length-1; z++)
                {
                    if (z<array.length-1)
                    System.out.print(array[z] + "x^" + z + "+");
                    if (z==array.length-1)
                    System.out.print(array[z] + "x^" + z);
                }



        }

    }


public class Class1D {

private int degree;
private int [] coefficient;
private double evaluation=0;

    public Class1D(int degree){
    this.degree =degree;
    }

    public Class1D(int degree, int[] a){

    this.degree =degree;
    this.coefficient = a.clone();
}

      public int []getCoefficient() {
          return coefficient;

      }
    public double Evaluathepolynomial(double value){
        for (int i =0; i<this.degree; i++)
        {
            this.evaluation= Math.pow(value,i) *this.coefficient[i];

            this.evaluation+= evaluation;

        }
        return evaluation;

}
}
```

Comment: You need a rubber duck - see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Based on a quick read, you're overwriting `this.evaluation`. You probably meant `double evaluation = Math.pow..`

Comment: DUDE thats not funny

Comment: double evaluation= Math.pow you mean I should remove the this?...by the way I just tried that and it stil says it equals 32

Comment: `this.evaluation= Math.pow(value,i) *this.coefficient[i];
            this.evaluation+= evaluation;` - examine this - where do you think `evaluation` is defined?

Comment: Also, FWIW, the rubber duck technique is no joke - it's widely used and helps catch the faults in your own code by talking through it out loud.

Comment: ok I have spent another hour now lookking at that code and trying to fix it and still nothing

Comment: Each time your loop goes around, that very first line overwrites everything it's done so far. The 32 comes from that very last coefficient only - i.e. you're getting `2 * 2 ^ 3`, 16, but then the line `this.evaluation+=evaluation;` basically doubles it again. I.e. `this.evaluation=16 + 16`.

Comment: As a simple proof of that, you can enter any coefficients for the first 3 and they'll have no effect at all. E.g. try `10083 9812376 42 2` - still 32 :)

Comment: I see from your profile that you're a talented programmer, can you please explain why it was doing what it was doing and why using this.sum +=evaluation fixes the problem?. I think its because this.sum originally equals null so the values of evaluation are just added one after the other...is that it?

Comment: I've just dropped it all in as an answer - hopefully that makes things easier for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, a quick example - my approach would look something like this (using everything else in the question):

```
public class Class1D {

    private int degree;
    private int [] coefficient;
    // private double evaluation=0; (Remove this!)

    public Class1D(int degree){
        this.degree =degree;
    }

    public Class1D(int degree, int[] a){

        this.degree =degree;
        this.coefficient = a.clone();
    }

    public int []getCoefficient() {
        return coefficient;  
    }

    public double Evaluathepolynomial(double value){

        // This will be the output:
        double total=0;

        // For each degree..
        for (int i =0; i<this.degree; i++)
        {

            // The current one is..
            double evaluation = Math.pow(value,i) *this.coefficient[i];

            // Add it into the total:
            // (same as total+=evaluation)
            total = total + evaluation;

        }

        // We're done! Return that total:
        return total;

    }
}
```

## What's going on?

The first thing to keep in mind is that a variable can only hold on to one thing at a time. So, if you do something like this:

```
double a;
a=1;
a=2;
a=14;

// a is now 14.
```

A will be `14`. Those other lines are essentially being ignored, because `a` will only hold whatever it was you set to it last.

Alright so let's take a look at your original loop:

```
 for (int i =0; i<this.degree; i++)
 {
     this.evaluation= Math.pow(value,i) *this.coefficient[i];
     this.evaluation+= evaluation;

 }

 return evaluation;
```

Firstly, keep in mind that all it's doing is repeating those lines inside the loop over and over - however many times you specify. So, for easy visualising, let's say "degree" is 3 and *unravel* the loop - that just means duplicate the lines and remove the loop:

```
 // i=0
 this.evaluation= Math.pow(value,0) *this.coefficient[0];
 this.evaluation+= evaluation;

 // i=1
 this.evaluation= Math.pow(value,1) *this.coefficient[1];
 this.evaluation+= evaluation;

 // i=2
 this.evaluation= Math.pow(value,2) *this.coefficient[2];
 this.evaluation+= evaluation;
```

Secondly, it's also worth mentioning that `this.evaluation` and `evaluation` are referring to the *same variable*.

Hopefully it's starting to be a little clearer as to what's going on - each *iteration* of the loop is completely overwriting the results of the previous one. Let's simplify it further:

```
// i=0
evaluation=2; // It's 2
evaluation+=evaluation; // 2+2; it's now 4

// i=1
evaluation=10; // It's 10. It's now like that 4 never even happened!
evaluation+=evaluation; // 10+10; it's now 20
```

This meant that in your original code, **only the last coefficient ever mattered**. With a degree of `4` and that last coefficient being 2, that 32 occured like this:

```
 this.evaluation= Math.pow(2,3) *2; // 16
 this.evaluation+= evaluation; // evaluation = 16+16 = 32
```

The simple route is to introduce a second variable, so the solution is more like this:

```
 a=0; // a is now 0

 b=14;
 a+=b; // a is now 14

 b=20;
 a+=b; // a is now 34
```

Or the other alternative using one variable is to directly add it in:

```
 a+=14; // a is now 14

 a+=20; // a is now 34
```

That would look like this:

```
total += Math.pow(value,i) *this.coefficient[i];
```

## Debugging

Hopefully the above helped make it clear what was going on, and why both the approach above and your answer are working. Importantly though, stepping through your code a line at a time and clearly stating what it's supposed to be doing is a big component of successful debugging. Many people find it really convenient to literally speak it out (I know I do!) because you'll very quickly spot what's going wrong that way. Dropping in `println` calls or adding breakpoints to double check it's actually doing what you describe is vital too.

Comment: Thank you very much Luke for taking the time to explain everything in such a throughout manner. So you're nice and talented?...well what a catch you must be...Anyway after spending hours trying to find the issue I'm sure to never make that mistake again!I'll try your debugging approach although its not the best idea when I'm at the library .Have a great week

Comment: @theredfox24 Haha thanks very much! I'm very humbled :)  No problem at all - I'm glad it made sense for you; have a great week too!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed the problem: I started printing out the values after each time the loop executes and I realized that the calculation is being performed correctly.However the part which was incorrect was the evaluation+=evaluation;. It wasnt working the way I imagined it would or should.Anyway...so I created a new instance field called private double sum and instead of writing evaluation+= evaluation I used this.sum+=evaluation; 
See code below:
Also this is the new OUTPUT. Please see that it's displaying the correct sum this time:

2 2 2 2 (coefficients that were entered)
You are evaluating for a value of: 2.0 (the value for which the polynomial is being evaluated)

2.0
4.0
8.0
16.0
16.0
(ignore above just debugging values while I was trying to solve the issue)
 The sum of the polynomial is:
30.0 (this is the correct sum)
2x^0+2x^1+2x^2+2x^3 (this is the polynomial that was evaluated x=2 by the way)

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class copy1D{

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {

        String input;
        int degree;
        double number;


        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" what is the degree of the polynomial?");
        degree = Integer.parseInt(input);
        degree= degree+1;
        int [] array = new int [degree];

        //creating array of coefficients
        for ( int i =0; i<=array.length-1; i++)
        {
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter coefficients:");
            array[i] = Integer.parseInt(input);
        }

        //Printing out the coefficients to ensure they are correct
        for ( int i =0; i<=array.length-1; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }



        Class1D c1d = new Class1D(degree, array);


        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter the number for which to evaluate the expression:");
            number = Integer.parseInt(input);
            System.out.println(" You are evaluating for a value of: " + number);
            System.out.println(" The sum of the polynomial is:");
            c1d.Evaluathepolynomial(number);
            System.out.println(c1d.getEvaluation());

            for (int z=0; z <= array.length-1; z++)
            {
                if (z<array.length-1)
                System.out.print(array[z] + "x^" + z + "+");
                if (z==array.length-1)
                System.out.print(array[z] + "x^" + z);
            }



    }

}



    public Class1D(int degree){
    this.degree =degree;
    }

    public Class1D(int degree, int[] a){

    this.degree =degree;
    this.coefficient = a.clone();
}

      public int []getCoefficient() {
          return coefficient;

      }

    public void Evaluathepolynomial(double value){
        this.value =value;

        for (int i =0; i<this.degree; i++)
        {
            evaluation= Math.pow(this.value,i) *this.coefficient[i];
            System.out.println(evaluation);
            this.sum+= evaluation;


        }
        System.out.println(evaluation);
    }
        public double getEvaluation()
        {
            return sum;
        }



}
```